# How to get access to dynamically generated radio buttons using POST

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have some dynamically generated HTML radio buttons based on fetching each character from a database table as show below:

```
<form name="form" id="myForm" method="POST" action="process.php">
<?php
$stmt = $this->registry->db->getDB()->prepare("SELECT * FROM characters");
$stmt->execute();


    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
      {
        foreach($stmt as $row)
        {
        ?>          
        <input type="radio" name="<?php print $row[0];?>" value="<?php print "value" . $row[1];?>">
        <?php
        }    
      }
?>
</form>
```

How would I get access to each selected radio button that is generated in my PHP script using `$_POST[]`, because the `name` attribute of each radio button is created dynamically, I can't get my head around how I would access each radio button value in PHP so I can process the form.

Note that each radio button generated will be unique so they will not be grouped with the same name.

Comment: Could you please state why you down voted this question rather than just hitting the button and wondering off. It would actually help people who come across similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to create an array, in this case `data[]`:

```
<input type="radio" name="data[<?php print $row[0];?>]" value="<?php print $row[1];?>">
```

Then to get them:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name = $value<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have just tried this, the `if(isset($_POST['data']))...` fails, seems like it can't pick up the `data` name.

Comment: I have got my radio buttons in a hidden modal (using jQuery's `.hide()` function), would that be the reason why it cannot be found by the PHP?

Comment: Maybe.  I'm not a jQuery guy so maybe update question with jQuery code and add  a tag.